# Flashdisk recognized as portable device but not showing in Explorer and Disk Management

Tags: usb-flash-drive, device-manager

I have a flash disk that's showing in my PC as a portable device with the letter F, but not showing up in Explorer and Disk Management.

Please help.

Comment: Then how can you know it's there?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get https://www.hirensbootcd.org/
2. Extract the archive
3. Go to apps folder and run Partition Wizard.
4. Check the flash disk, recover it if it is required.